# localhost vs real ip address

Tags: tcp

What is the difference between the localhost and the real ip address?

If I access an application by using `http://localhost:8080/index.html` and `http://192.123.456.001:8080/index.html` (for example, 192.123.456.001 is the real ip address of the host computer), what is the difference?

Comment: *192.123.456.001* isn't a real IP address :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you access `localhost`, your `/etc/hosts` file will tell your computer not to look any further and redirects you to your own computer. When you access the local IP adress, your computer will ask the router to fetch the data, and your router will then point back to your computer.

Comment: I think some modern systems recognize if the external IP address they are talking to is their own, and won't bother round tripping the traffic out to the network, but I can't remember off the top of my head which ones do this, or if there are any limitations to this.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to the other answers you can run into mysterious problems with using localhost.

One example: IE on Windows makes a shortcut if you enter http://localhost into the URL bar. That becomes a problem when you are developing a web application and have a local proxy installed (such as Fiddler) to peek into messages passing between the client webpage and the server both running locally - the message will not be captured because it will not pass through the proxy in this case. Which makes it a bit inconvenient to find IE-only bugs in your application... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia, the pertinent points:

> Communicating with the loopback interface in an identical manner as
>   with another computers on the network, but bypassing the local network
>   interface hardware, is useful for the purposes of testing software.
>
> Connecting to locally hosted network services, such as a computer game
>   server, or for other inter-process communications, can be performed
>   through loopback addresses in a highly efficient manner.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Although, it would be nice to know *how* this is "a highly efficient manner."  is it efficient for the programmer to not think about the server address? Is it efficient for the server to not have to look up where the address is? Both?  I think that's what the original poster was asking.

Comment: @Skotte networking follows the OSI 7-layer model, running loopback allows the OS to optimize things by skipping layers.  On a modern OS and TCP/IP the difference should be as minimal as simply the lookup in the local routing table.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when you set up a listening socket (waiting for a connection) you have to tell it which address to bind to. The same applies for website configuration with all of the common web servers.

Normally you will just bind to any address, which means you can access it via 127.0.0.1 or 192.x.x.x or whatever other IP addresses the machine happens to have, but occasionally you may want to bind to a specific one - e.g. if you have 4 public IPs on one machine you may want to have a specific site on a specific IP.