# Unable to send request via live server

Tags: jboss, server

when I am sending request to `http://localhost:8080/..`it works perfectly

but when I send request to `http://10.68.5.39:8080/..`

I am getting error..

Ip address 10.68.5.39 is working in intranet and port 8080 is open

Please see..

Comment: possible duplicate of [localhost vs real ip address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938039/localhost-vs-real-ip-address)

Answer (score 3):

In standalone.xml file try to change the alias name from **localhost** to your **IP Address**

```
<server name="default-server">
   <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
       <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
           <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
           <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
           <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
       </host>
</server>
```

It worked for me.