# glyphicon not loaded in IE 7 (while accessing from IP )

Tags: html, css, ip, glyphicons

I am working on a web project. 
and I am using glyphicon for ICON.
It's working well in other than IE (7 version above )browser. But there in IE 7 glyphicon could not loaded so, i use [glyphicons-ie7.css](https://github.com/yargalot/glyphicons-bootstrap3-ie7/blob/master/glyphicons-ie7.css). It's working while I am browsing page from local machine(ie. http://localhost:70/) but not working while accessing from my local IP(ie. http://192.168.0.240:70/). :(

following is screenshot of my problem.

This is a screenshot from localhost
[image: This is a screenshot from localhost]

This is a screenshot of a page accessing from my local IP address

[image: This is a screenshot of a page accessing from my local IP address]

Comment: Could you possibly show us the code, that you used with your navigation items?

Comment: could you please tell me which code? default bootstrap or something else ?

Comment: The navigation items that are on the left side,(Active Teasers, Archive Teasers etc...)

Comment: <li id="menu-ActiveTeasers">
                <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>ActiveTeasers">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    <?php echo $Language->translate("Active Teasers") ?>
                    <span class="pull-right numberCircle"
                          style="background: #636363"><?php echo $_SESSION['ActiverTeaserCount'] ?></span>
                </a>
            </li>


it is something like this

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning this, but I meant the CSS. And could you put the CSS inside the question?

Comment: This is the class : glyphicon glyphicon-time and css are default css of bootstrap , there is not any other customization .

Answer (score 0):

> When you access `localhost`, your `/etc/hosts` file will tell your
>   computer not to look any further and redirects you to your own
>   computer. When you access the local IP adress, your computer will ask
>   the router to fetch the data, and your router will then point back to
>   your computer.

In your case, the router can't get the glyphicons in the right way..  ([See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938039/localhost-vs-real-ip-address))